# Int? to CLBeaconMajorValue

Tags: ios, swift

I started with apple swift today (as many others ;)) and I struggle with reading a plist.

I read a plist entry from my info.plist which is an NSArray where each entry is a Dictionary.

```
let regionsToMonitor = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary["Regions"] as Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>

for regionToMonitor in regionsToMonitor {
    ...
```

one key for each region is a major. in objC terms a NSNumber. I read it as:

```
let major: Int? = regionToMonitor["major"] ? regionToMonitor["major"]!.integerValue : nil;
```

now I need it as a CLBeaconMajorValue

so I try to cast it to that with `as`

```
                clRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid,
                    major: major! as CLBeaconMajorValue,
                    identifier: identifier)
```

doesn't work. the UUID and identifier do work (Ive checked with another constructor, but the not the init

this is also not good

```
                let m = major! as CLBeaconMajorValue
```

how do I convert my NSNumber / int? to the CLBeaconMajorValue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to cast the value.

Since `CLBeaconMajorValue` is a `UInt16` `typealias`, you can do it like this:

```
let m = UInt16(major!)
```

You can even do this:

```
let m = CLBeaconMajorValue(major!)
```

Comment: why CLBeaconMajorValue(x)?

Comment: let m = major! as CLBeaconMajorValue -- that was my try